# What are the concerns with using a hash table with a low # of inputs?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashtable

What are the concerns with using a hash table with a low # of inputs? Are there better options in terms of what ADT to use with similar properties?

Comment: It might be easier to answer this question if you gave us some idea of what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: Nothing, it's a question on a practice exam that I'm not sure how to answer

Comment: That's what I originally thought but you can set the size of the hash table....I mean if the # inputs is not known at compile time (assuming you don't dynamically size it) then yeah it's a waste of space....so it's only a waste of space in that situation right? Otherwise I don't really see a problem

Comment: Maybe an unordered_map would suffice? With a hash function? lol is that plausible?

Comment: A linear search in a small `vector` is often surprisingly fast compared with data structures that have better-complexity lookup. But I don't necessarily expect that to be the correct answer to an exam question.

Comment: Do you think that's also true versus the speed of lookup in an open-addressed hash table? I thought the search time of a vector is O(N) @SteveJessop

Comment: @Riptyde4: Well, I don't know what "low" is. My generalization is sufficiently true that if I have a data structure with mean size 1 and mode size 0, then I would be reluctant to use anything other than a `vector`. The point is that by specifying that `N` is small you make complexity *completely irrelevant*, and as a consequence it is sometimes misleading.

Comment: In fact you could almost define "small" in any given context to mean, "below the size at which things behave as you'd expect according to their size". Larger than that isn't "small", it's "normal-sized" ;-) Then you just have to work out how small "small" is for a given problem, and therefore whether to expect differences from normality.

Comment: It's just a relative term to the norm I guess, I agree it's sort of vague...

Comment: "Maybe an unordered_map would suffice? With a hash function?" - an `unordered_map` *is* a hash table. ;-)

Comment: @TonyD that would make sense actually. lol

Comment: @TonyD but many hash maps aren't strictly `unordered_map` s

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: agreed, `unordered_map` is just the C++11 Standard's hash table.  But given "Are there better options [than "using a hash table"] in terms of what ADT to use with similar properties?" and Riptyde4's later comment "Maybe an unordered_map would suffice? With a hash function? lol is that plausible?" he seemed to think `unordered_map` was an alternative to a hash table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if every operation in a hash table was O(1), it would still have a fairly high constant cost in terms of construction (e.g. constructing buckets). With only a few elements, many other ADTs (e.g. LinkedList) will perform better in practice (even if using those data structures has a O(n log n) or even a O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity).

Comment: In terms of space complexity or overhead in creating the object itself?

Comment: In the broadest sense, in amortized constant time operations, the time being amortized cannot "payoff" if the # of elements is small. That is, there is a constant runtime overhead (for example, in constructing the buckets).

Comment: I'm not really sure which operations you're talking about on which data structures that takes O(n log n) or O(n^2). Sounds like sorting, but where does that come into the picture?

Comment: Every operation is not O(1), most are amortized average case.  O() is worst case.  Hash insertion in particular can be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers of entries, `vector`s tend to work very well - crucially, the objects are stored contiguously which tends to work best with memory caching - in modern systems that can be so beneficial it overwhelms costs of brute-force searching, and moving objects when erasing/sorting etc..

If you need to minimise moving/copying of the objects then a `vector` of (smart) pointers or linked `list` may suit.

Hash tables have to hash the element keys, while `std::map` and `std::find` in `vector` etc. do element comparisons.  For example, high quality hashing of ints is more expensive than just comparing the values, but a one-off hash of a large matrix of values is then much faster to compare against other matrices than the maxtrix comparisons would be - particularly if they only differ in data well into the comparison.